# Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution and area under the curve

Tags: thermodynamics, probability, asymptotics

If the curve of MBDist is asymptotic on the x-axis does this mean the area under the curve (no. of particles) is infinite?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the integration and find out. The distribution is a probability density, so the area underneath the curve for a range of velocities represents the probability of finding a particle that has a velocity within that range. This probability must be finite, and for example, in the 1D case, is normalised to be equal to $1/2$. The $1/2$ comes from the $\pm$ velocity contributions. The 1D distribution is given by

$$f(v_x)dv_x=\sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi kT}}e^{-\frac{mv_x^2}{2kT}}dv_x.$$

Integrating from $v_x=0\rightarrow\infty$, gives $p=1/2$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My mathematics is not that great I'm afraid. What does this say about the number of particles? Their number tends towards zero? There always is the same area under the curve no matter what the shape is though, right? Tall or more stretched out.

Comment: @greenplasticdave As the area under the curve over a range of velocities represents the probability of a particle having a velocity within that range. For very large velocities this probability tends towrds zero, so it is highly unlikely that a particle within a thermal gas has a velocity in the far regions of the tail. Yes, the area is always normalised such that it can be represented as a probability.

Comment: Thank you. So it's not strictly 'number of particles' but probability of a particle having a given velocity?

Comment: It is a probability density. The area under the curve gives the probability.